# Rounding off a number in Elastic Search using Kibana interface

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-5

I am using Kibana interface for Elasticsearch. While I was creating a visualization which actually sums up probabilities in a column, the result is a floating point number. How do I round the floating point number using the JSON input in KIBANA?

The following image shows what I have tried. But it is not working.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: what is the version of ES here ?

Comment: The version I am using is 5.5

Comment: anything worked ?

Comment: No. I tried multiple ways, but nothing worked. There is no round function present in the Lacene Expressions being used in Elastic Search

Answer (score 0):

There was a healthy discussion around this for Kiabana - 4.1

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/kibana-4-1-metric-visualization-round-decimal-value/24098

You can try the steps on 5.5 too.
This was added as issue for Kibana backlog but not sure it was picked or not.
Let us know if it works!

Comment: This works when you want to change the type of the entire field itself. But when you want to round a metric after aggregation, there is no way I could find.